Prove that open balls are preserved under scalar multiplication
Suppose we have a random ball $B_r(x)$ in $ \mathbb{R²}$, and we use the vector space structure and scale this ball down by a non zero scalar $a$. I believe that,  $\frac{B_r(x)}{a}= B_{r'}(x')$.
My attempt:
$$B_r(x) = \{   |x-b| < r |  b\}$$
$$\frac{B_r(x)}{a} = \{   |x-b| < r |  \frac{b}{a} \}$$
Now, I am not sure how to proceed...

Hint: multiplication by a non-zero scalar is a bijection, so you can rewrite your second expression as ${c : |x - ca| < r}$.

Show that if $d(y,a)\lt r\implies d(ky,ka)\lt kr$ for positive $k$.

Not sure if you intended to say random; perhaps you meant arbitrary?
Now, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and any $\rho > 0,$ define $$\overset{\circ}{B}(x;\rho) = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, \| y - x \| < \rho \}$$ (here, we take $\| \cdot \|$ to be the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$). Take $(x,\rho) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times (0,+\infty).$ Then, for any $\alpha \in (0,+\infty),$ we have the following:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\alpha}\overset{\circ}{B}(x;\rho) &= \frac{1}{\alpha} \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, \| y - x \| < \rho \} \\
&= \{ y / \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, \| y - x \| < \rho \} \\
&= \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, \| \alpha y - x \| < \rho \} \\
&= \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, \alpha \| y - x / \alpha \| < \rho \} \\
&= \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, \| y - x / \alpha \| < \rho / \alpha \} \\
&= \overset{\circ}{B}(x/\alpha;\rho/\alpha).
\end{align*}
Note that more generally, one can show that
$$ \overset{\circ}{B}(x;\rho) = \{ x \} + \rho \overset{\circ}{B}(0_{\mathbb{R}^2};1), $$
where $0_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ is the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ and for any two vector spaces $A$ and $B,$
$$ A + B = \{ a + b \, | \, a \in A ~\textrm{and}~ b \in B \};$$
additionally, $\rho A = \{ \rho a \, | \, a \in A \}.$
This is called the Minkowski sum of $A$ and $B.$
